# Facebook Page Analysis Tool like "Likealyzer"

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, error-handling

I'd like to develop a tool like [Likealyzer](https://likealyzer.com/), where pages from Facebook are analyzed: posts, likes, comments and so on.

In my test with the Facebook Graph API I already got the error

> (# 32) page request limit reached

I wonder how these tools work, and how they look like does not exceed this limit. They use Graph API or something else?

Is there a way to handle this?

Thank you in advance for your reply

Comment: What call(s) were you making when you got that error?

Comment: yeah, without the specifics of your api calls it is impossible to help. you are obviously making too many calls, that is all we can tell you right now.

Comment: Calls like: FB.api('/{page-id}/feed?fields=shares....);

When I re-call the page count more calls, of course. But how can I at least test?